# Match string pattern in character vector

Tags: r, regex, function

I have a function that returns the school a major belongs to. I want the string comparison to allow partial matches so that if a major is "Art: Design," it matches with art_majors which contains the element "Art."

```
## function to find school by major
findschool <- function(major) {
  art_majors <- c("Art", "Design", "Classics", "French", "German", "Russian", "Spanish", "Romance Lanugage", "English", "Linguistics", "Music", "Theatre", "Creative Writing")
  business_majors <- c("Accounting", "Business Administration")
  health_majors <- c("Communication Disorders", "Health Science", "Exercise Science", "Athletic Training", "Nursing")
  science_majors <- c("Agricultural Science", "Biology", "Chemistry", "Computer Science", "Mathematics", "Physics", "Statistics")
  social_majors <- c("Communication", "Economics", "History", "Justice Systems", "Philosophy & Religion", "Political Science", "Psychology", "Sociology/Anthropology")
  ##major = format(as.character(major))
  print(major)
  if (any(str_detect(art_majors, major))) {
    "Arts & Letters"
  } else if (any(str_detect(business_majors, major))) {
    "Business"
  } else if (any(major %in% health_majors)) {
    "Health Sciences & Education"
  } else if (any(major %in% science_majors)) {
    "Science & Mathematics"
  } else if (any(major %in% social_majors)) {
    "Social & Cultural Studies"
  } else if (any(major %in% c("Undeclared", NA))) {
    NA
  } else {
    "Interdisciplinary Studies"
  }
}

## for full data
checkins.clean <- checkins.clean %>%
  mutate(School = findschool(major = trimws(Primary.Major)))
```

For example if we have:

```
checkins.clean <- data.frame("SN" = 1:2, "Name" = c("John", "Dora"), "Major" = c("Art: Studio", "Art"))
```

it should return

```
checkins.clean <- data.frame("SN" = 1:2, "Name" = c("John", "Dora"), "Major" = c("Art: Studio", "Art"), "School" = c("Arts & Letters", "Arts & Letters")
```

So "Art: Studio" should match with "Art" and return "Arts & Letters" from the above function.

The complication with using `str_detect` is it's not always clear that the left-hand side argument will be smaller/greater in terms of length than the right-hand side argument. Example: If someone's major was just "Business" that would fall under "Business Administration" in `business_majors` however, if it were "Business Administration: Finance," it would not be a subset of `business_majors`.

Should I be using regular expressions or something like that and how do I use them?

Comment: issue is also that `str_detect` is not detecting 'Art: Studio' when matched iwth 'Art'

Comment: @akrun You're right! That is a just a placeholder on my code for now.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do:

first ensure all the majors are in a list (Check the end `lst` is defined)
Now paste all of them together to create your pattern and do:

```
pat <- sapply(lst, paste0, collapse = "|")
a <-Vectorize(grepl,"pattern")(pat,checkins.clean$Major))
cbind(checkins.clean, a)

 SN Name       Major art_majors business_majors health_majors science_majors social_majors
1  1 John Art: Studio       TRUE           FALSE         FALSE          FALSE         FALSE
2  2 Dora         Art       TRUE           FALSE         FALSE          FALSE         FALSE
```

Now `a` contains the `TRUE/FALSE` that you need.
I still do not understand how you get the `NA` nd `Interdisplinary` from your code. Hence will stop at this point. Although, if you want, You could add more information on how to obtain those ones. Otherwise anything after this will be fruitless.

The data used:

```
lst <- list(art_majors = c("Art", "Design", "Classics", "French", "German", "Russian", "Spanish", "Romance Lanugage", "English", "Linguistics", "Music", "Theatre", "Creative Writing"),
           business_majors = c("Accounting","Business Administration"), 
           health_majors = c("Communication Disorders", "Health Science", "Exercise Science", "Athletic Training", "Nursing"),
           science_majors = c("Agricultural Science", "Biology", "Chemistry", "Computer Science", "Mathematics", "Physics", "Statistics"),
           social_majors = c("Communication", "Economics", "History", "Justice Systems", "Philosophy & Religion", "Political Science", "Psychology", "Sociology/Anthropology"))
```

Comment: Could you tell me what your first two lines of code are doing? I am having a hard time understanding them.